# Banana Pi & Buildroot

Tags: arm, buildroot, banana-pi

I'm trying to create a customized `FS` and eventually a kernel for my Banana Pi using `BuildRoot`.

The fact is I'm new to it. Banana Pi isn't part of the pre-made configurations.

My main problem is that can't find the specific hardware specs I'm searching for.

My CPU is an `Allwinner A20 SoC`, which has an `ARM` architecture. But is it Big or Little endian ?

**1. What is the "Target ABI" ?

2. What is its "Floating point strategy" ?**

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 2):

For both, you can chose whatever you want, since Buildroot will only show you what's compatible with the ARM core you've selected (in the case of the Allwinner A20, the ARM is Cortex-A7).

For the target ABI, you have the choice between EABI and EABIhf. Unless you need to use some pre-built binaries that are built with the EABI ABI, I would suggest you to use EABIhf, since it allows to pass floating point arguments directly in floating point registers (rather than through integer registers), which makes calling floating point related functions slightly more efficient.

For the Floating point strategy, use the higest VFPvX available for your ARM core.